# How do I find a variable set of 5 numbers qualified by surrounding underscores?

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, ssis, etl

I am pulling file names into a variable (`@[User::FileName]`) and attempting to extract the work order number (always 5 numbers with underscores on both sides) from that string. For example, a file name would look like - `"ABC_2017_DEF_9_12_GHI_35132_S5160.csv"`. I want result to return "35132". I have found examples of how to do it such as this `SUBSTRING(FileName,1,FINDSTRING(FileName,"_",1) - 1)` but the underscore will not always be in the same location.

Is it possible to do this in the expression builder?

### Answer:

```
public void Main()
{
    string strFilename = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
    var RegexObj = new Regex(@"_([\d]{5})_");
    var match = RegexObj.Match(strFilename);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::WorkOrder"].Value = match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the example you have provided `ABC_2017_DEF_9_12_GHI_35132_S5160.csv` contains 4 numbers located between underscores:

```
2017 , 9 , 12 , 35132
```

I don't know if the filename may contains many a 5 digits number can occurs many times, so in my answer i will assume that the number you want to return is the last occurrence of the number made of 5 digits.

## Solution

You have to use the Following Regular Expression:

```
(?:_)\K[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?=_)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/AzVAIf/1)

Or as [@MartinSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) Suggested *(in a comment)*, you can use the following RegEx:

```
_([\d]{5})_
```

### Implemeting RegEx in SSIS

1. First add another Variable (Ex: `@[User::FileNumber]`)
2. Add a Script Task and choose `@[User::Filename]` variable as ReadOnlyVariable, and `@[User:FileNumber]` as ReadWriteVariable
3. Inside the script task use the following code:

   ```
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   public void Main()
   {

       string strFilename = Dts.Variables["filename"].Value.ToString();
       string strNumber;
       var objRegEx = new Regex(@"(?:_)\K[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?=_)");
       var mc = objRegEx.Matches(strFilename);


       //The last match contains the value needed
       strNumber = mc[mc.Count - 1].Value;


       Dts.Variables["FileNumber"].Value.ToString();

       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   }
   ```

Comment: They are looking for a five digit number surrounded by underscores. Like this http://rextester.com/NNQN26938

Comment: @MartinSmith i agree with that. but both RegEx are working, but i added the RegEx you provided to my answer

Comment: Ah right TBH i just saw the first line where you mentioned four numbers located between underscores and thought you'd misinterpreted the Q. What is `\K` in a regex?

Comment: `\K` Sets the given position in the regex as the new "start" of the match. This means that nothing preceding the K will be captured in the overall match.

Comment: Ta! Haven't come across that before.

Comment: You guys are awesome!! This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you so much! I would have been struggling at this all day and wouldn't have gotten anywhere! Are there any good resources that you recommend that I can learn some of this stuff? I'm fairly new (3 months) to SSIS packages but have an associates degree in programming with a focus on C++ and Java, so I'm not completely lost, but could learn a WHOLE lot more.

Comment: [Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Integration Services](https://www.amazon.com/Professional-Microsoft-Server-Integration-Services/dp/111810112X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIIBINOD46VC3JCLQ%26tag%3Dstackoverfl08-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D111810112X)

Comment: @Hadi I'm getting this error message when the package runs the script: https://pastebin.com/gNV6NA3p

Comment: This is the stack trace not the error message. Note that variable name are case sensitive

Comment: @Hadi Sorry, the actual error is a runtime error obviously. "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." on Project Name: ST_e2812fa1408345ea89dff5f854f1ceea which is the name of the script. The actual name of the package is File Stage In. I did rename your variables to "User::FileName" and "User::WorkOrder" which is what my variables are. Any ideas?

Comment: @Hadi Ok, after removing `MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(strFilename, @"(?:_)\K[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?=_)");

            //The last match contains the value needed
            strNumber = mc[mc.Count - 1].Value;` the script ran...

Comment: @Hadi Ah, ok. So now you're creating an object and passing it the value of the string. Was the previous code wrong or was I just not using it correctly?

Comment: @BlakeA.Norwood No, both code are correct. but i think it is related to the script task references or something else

Comment: @Hadi unfortunately I still couldn't get that one to run... (I did remove "New" before the objRegEx since that shouldn't be there). But I did make a mashup of your and Martin Smith's codes to get a working solution! I'm not sure what else is going on with the one you wrote. I can't figure that one out... I added my solution to my question at the top.

Answer (score 1):

do the other pieces mean something?

anyway you can use a script task and split function.

pass in @fileName as readonly, and @WO as readwrite

```
string fn = Dts.Variables["fileName"].Value; 
string[] parts = fn.Split('_');

//Assuming it's always the 7th part 
// You could extract the other    parts as well. 
Dts.Variables["WO"].Value = part(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a Script Transformation (or Script Task if this is not in a DataFlow) and use a Regex.